# How to include @apply CSS code for reusing TailwindCSS styles with tailwindcss-rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, asset-pipeline

I’m using [tailwindcss-rails](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails) gem in Rails 7 project with asset pipeline. I need to [reuse TailwindCSS styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles), for example:

```
.pagy-nav {
  @apply flex space-x-2;
}
```

I can put this code in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css` file and it works:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.pagy-nav {
  @apply flex space-x-2;
}
```

However, I want to put the `.pagy-nav` code into a separate css file pagy.css (to be more clean/organised). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@import` works out of the box since *tailwindcss-rails* `v2.0.10` (*tailwindcss* `v3.1.2`):
*https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8580*

```
@import "./pagy_nav.css"; // import must come first, because `postcss-import` says so.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Or switch everything to import:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "./pagy_nav.css";
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Are there any advantages of using the first or the second approach? Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @Evgenii with the second approach you can reorder imports (otherwise, they are equivalent). given the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) you might want to put your imports after *@tailwind*, so that they would take priority. you can also use [`@layer`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer) directives for the same purpose.